# Footer "Sister Sites" link inconsistency

Tags: feature-request, usability, footer

It would seem as if "serverfault.com" should read as "serverfault" like all other sister site links in the footer.  Likewise the same change should be applied to both "stackoverflow.com" and "superuser.com".

[image]

Comment: And the same for *stackoverflow.com* and *superuser.com*, presumably?

Comment: Yup, I didn't even notice that.  Editing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just my personal opinion but I don't agree with this at all.

I would imagine the reason why Stack Overflow, Server Fault & Super User all use `.com` in their links is because they have their own domains and are part of the trilogy. The founders of Stack Exchange if you like.

The rest of the sister sites are all Stack Exchange 2.0 sites and all "live" on the `*.stackexchange.com` domain.